# Using c:forEach tag with Google App Engine

Tags: html, google-app-engine, jsp, jstl

I am trying to populate an HTML table with values from my entity "Log."

```
Query query = new Query("Log", logkey)
List<Entity> logs = datastore.prepare(query).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(1000));
```

using `pageContext.setAttribute("age_content", log.getProperty("age"));` to display all age properties in table with `<td>${log.age_content}</td>`. Right now, the code produces individual tables for each age and user. How can I make use of the c:forEach tag in my jsp file to iterate over all logs and produce one table? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

writing jstl would not be different if you do not use google app engine.

```
<c:forEach items="${logs}" var="log" varStatus="status">
    <td>${log.age_content}</td>
</c:forEach>
```

dont forget to add this in your jsp begining

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

Comment: Should the forEach tag be used to display the properties in the table or earlier on where the properties are retrieved? Right now I'm using a for loop to set the attributes... 

for (Entity log : logs) {
pageContext.setAttribute("age_content", log.getProperty("age"));